# eclipse error - org/eclipse/ui/internal/util/SWTResourceUtil

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this error while creating reveng file of hibernat.

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/ui/internal/util/SWTResourceUtil
```

Please guide me if anyone have idea about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See error log for more details (and show them) ;) - OK, there is an error log view in eclipse. Open that and look what exactly went wrong. Just "an error occured" is not enough information (crystal balls not polished yet)

Comment: Errors with resources *may* occur if some files in the workspace have been changed from outside. Refresh the projects and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem on Eclipse when using Eclipse Juno with JBoss Tools (both the nightly build for Juno and the stable build for Indigo). The solution in my case was to use Eclipse Indigo with an stable JBoss Tools for Indigo.

As JBoss Tools includes some Hibernate plugins, this might also be the cause for your problem.